# Upload Large Video to PHP Server from Android Crashes Application

Tags: android, video, file-upload, upload

I am uploading large video to php server, which crashes application.

So, I have used   **conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(maxBufferSize);**

But it gives **RESPONCE : Request Entity Too Large**

Server side Video is accepted in encoded form, so I used Base64 to encode.

I am using JSON web-service to Upload video

```
    uploadvideo(&userid,&video,&title,&description,&type)
```

I have searched many but Can't get solution.
Can any-one tell me

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/03/29/uploading-audio-video-or-image-files-from-android-to-server/

http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg92856.html

which one is better AND HOW TO ADD PARAMETERS?

I have used code somethin  like dis

```
try {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(myFile.getAbsolutePath());        //(new File(selectedPath) );
    // open a URL connection to the Servlet
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    // Allow Inputs
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    // Allow Outputs
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    // Don't use a cached copy.
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    // Use a post method.
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(maxBufferSize);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

    dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userid\""+ lineEnd + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(strUserid+lineEnd);

    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // read file and write it into form...
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }
    String encodeurl = Base64.encodeBytes(buffer);

    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video\""+ lineEnd + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(encodeurl+lineEnd);

    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\""+ lineEnd + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(strVideoName+lineEnd);

    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"description\""+ lineEnd + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(strVideoComments+lineEnd);

    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"type\""+ lineEnd + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(type+lineEnd);

    responseMsg = conn.getResponseMessage();
    // close streams
    System.out.println("Debug  File is written");
    fileInputStream.close();
    dos.flush();
    dos.close();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(("Debug  Error: " + ex.getMessage()));
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        System.out.println("Debug  Error: " + ioe.getMessage());
    }
    //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
    try {
        inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
        System.out.println("Input Stream :: "+inStream.toString());
        String str;

        while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Debug  Server Response "+str);
        }
        inStream.close();

    }
    catch (IOException ioex){
         System.out.println("Debug  Error: " + ioex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Hi chintan i am facing the same problem with my code can you help how you have implemented if it is solved. I am using same source it uploads only <12 MB of video not if more then that size. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

you should divide the large file into small parts then try to sending.And Join this small part on the server

Answer (score 0):

Send the data in chunks using `conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);`
and buffersize should be `int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024;`